# Tkinter: Pack new widgets below other widgets

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to pack the button below the Text and Scrollbar widget.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

try:
  from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
  from tkinter import *

class Chat(Frame):
  def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.pack(anchor=N, fill=BOTH)
    self.create_widgets()
    self.count = 0

  def create_widgets(self):
    self.scrolly = Scrollbar(self)
    self.scrolly.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    self.chattext = Text(self, borderwidth=5, yscrollcommand=self.scrolly.set)
    self.chattext.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.scrolly.config(command=Text.yview(self.chattext))
    self.button1 = Button(self, text="Add text", command=self.add_text)
    self.button1.pack()

  def add_text(self):
    self.count += 1
    self.chattext.insert("end", "%i\n" % self.count)
    self.chattext.update_idletasks()


def main():
  root = Tk()
  root.title("Test Chat Client")
  root.geometry("600x500")
  #root.resizable(0,0)
  app = Chat(root)

  root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This is what it looks like
[image: What it looks like]

I want the button to be below and not in between the other widgets.

I have tried the following:

```
self.button1.pack(after=self.scrolly)
self.button1.pack(after=self.chattext)
```

How may i pack the button at the bottom?

Another issue is that the scrollbar does not work, when i try to scroll nothing happens. 
(Yes, i have tried to fill the Text widget with alot of lines, more than it can view.)

Also, why is the scrollbar viewed/packed outside/"far" away from the Text widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the grid geometry manager instead.

http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html

Comment: Thank you. Now Everything is at the correct position and i managed to fix the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider replacing the text field with a [ScrolledText](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html) field.
It's a lot easier to use and doesn't require manual scrollbar placement.
(Don't use `pack` to place it though. Use `grid`)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst

self.chattext = tkst.ScrolledText(
    master = self,
    wrap   = tk.WORD,
    width  = 20,
    height = 10
)
```